# Can a transnational marriage be performed over international waters?

Tags: weddings, international-waters

Me and my fiancé are from two different countries. If we wouldn’t need a visa to get married over a cruise or in international waters, could we legally get married?

Comment: You can get legally married in many countries if you have the proper visa.  In many countries, the proper visa is any visa, including a tourist visa.  If you can [edit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/153202/edit) the question to mention the countries, you might get some helpful suggestions.  In some countries, the laws vary by state or province.  For example, Nevada is well known for permitting nonresidents to marry, but there are others.

Comment: Keep in mind, there's a huge difference between legal marriage and solemn marriage.  So you can take care of all the legal issues any time and have the ceremony anywhere you want performed any way you want.

Comment: @NeanDerThal I don't see why this question is a duplicate. The question here is not if a ship's captain is allowed to perform a wedding, but if it is possible to marry in international waters. Many cruise operators offer 'marriage packages' to do so. Nevertheless, at least captains on ships flagged in Malta, Bermuda and Bahamas are indeed entitled to perform weddings.

Comment: What you probably care about is whether the marriage would be recognized in your home countries.  That will depend on the laws of those countries; since you haven't said what countries those are, this can't really be answered with certainty.